# Operator precedence and pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, pointers, scope, rvalue

Given the following code:

```
void Allocate(int *p)
{
    p = new int;
    *p++ = 2;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    Allocate(&i);
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

I'm a bit confised about the meaning of:

```
*p++ = 2;
```

The output is `10` and my reasoning as to why this is the case is that `*p++` is a temporary therefore any assignment to it is lost at the end of the scope of `Allocate(int *p)`.

Is this the case?
Thanks in adv!

Comment: You should be careful when doing something like this. You're on the brink of undefined behaviour by incrementing that pointer. Any operation other than moving it one place ahead would have been undefined behaviour due to it going outside of an array or one past the end, keeping in mind that single variables are treated like single element arrays for the purpose of pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you pass the the address of i into Allocate, another (temp) pointer is created that points to i's address (i.e. passing by pointer). then that temp pointer is pointed to a new location (via new int). thus the value of i is left alone.

[image: here's a crappy illustration i drew]

Comment: So because the Allocate(int *p) makes a temporary copy, only that copy is worked upon, thus the original is left unchanged?

Comment: @PatMustard, Yes, the pointer is copied, but still points to the same location (`&i`). If it wasn't, you'd run into quite a few problems trying to modify the address of `i`.

Comment: Given the above, you're likely smashing your stack or base pointer (since the stack grows up). Either way - nothing good will happen and if you did this in real code, have fun tracking down the error.

Answer (score 4):

- On input to `Allocate`, `p` points to the variable `i` in the `main`
  function.
- The address of this variable then lost and replaced by the
  `new int`.
- The value of this int (which is uninitialized and so could
  start as anything) is set to 2.
- The `p` pointer is incremented.
- The `Allocate` function returns at this point, leaking the int that was
  allocated.
- The value of `i` in the `main` function is unchanged,
  because `Allocate` did not modify it.

Answer (score 3):

```
p = new int;
```

You're assigning `p` new memory to point to instead of what it was pointing to before. You then change this newly allocated memory and it's lost forever when the function ends, causing a memory leak. If you remove the allocation line, it should cause an output of 2. The ++ does nothing in this case. It just increments the pointer and returns the old value to dereference.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you enter `Allocate`, you assign `p` to point to a new block of memory, so it no longer points to `i`. Then you modify that new block of memory (which is then leaked when the method returns.) `i` is unaffected because you've moved that pointer before you set the pointed-to memory cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Allocate(int **p)
{
    *p = new int;
    **p = 2;
}


int main()
{
    int j = 10;
    int *i = &j;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    Allocate(&i);
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Output is :
   10
   2

You need a pointer to pointer to change the address of the location being pointed to.